# How to keep screen consistent even after pressing back or exit button in Android

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio as a development platform for Android App Development.
I have implemented a module of OTP screen for OTP verfication.

I want to achieve following things:

1. The OTP screen should be consistent even if the user presses back or home screen like PAYTM & app should run in background untill the OTP is not confirmed.
2. The OTP section should automatically read the incoming message so.
3. I also want to get the permissions how to set that permission thing
   like permission to read sms, permission to read contact which will
   either ask allow or deny.

I am new to this thing and I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

1) Please read about Intent Services, which work in the background thread.
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

So you can override the onBackPressed() method in your activity, depends on it(which is connected with Broadcast Receivers)

2) Read about Broadcast Receivers. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

3) If it comes to permissions in Android  API > 23, you need to add them to manifest and also ask at runtime. You can see documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html